# How to break a quadratic form based on two complementary subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I'd like to prove the following for my research, but I don't know how. It's from the paper [*An Elementary Proof of the Restricted Invertibility Theorem*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.1114v4.pdf) by Daniel A. Spielman and Nikhil Srivastava.

---

Let's say I have a [positive semi-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a (maybe non-symmetric) matrix $\mathbf{L}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Basically, I want to compute some values related to $Tr(\mathbf{L}^T(\mathbf{A}-b\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{L})$. (It's guaranteed that $(\mathbf{A}-b\mathbf{I})^{-1}$ always exists and it is also positive semi-definite.)

Now, let's say $\mathbf{P}$ is the projection onto the image of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$ is the projection onto its kernel, so that $\mathbf{P} + \mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{I}$. Then how can you prove the following?

$$Tr(\mathbf{L}^T(\mathbf{A}-b\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{L}) = 
Tr(\mathbf{L}^T\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{A}-b\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{P}\mathbf{L}) + 
Tr(\mathbf{L}^T\mathbf{Z}(\mathbf{A}-b\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{L})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** note that $P+Z=I$ yields 
$$
X=PXP+PXZ+ZXP+ZXZ.
$$
Apply this to $X:=(A-bI)^{-1}$. Left-multiply by $L^T$, right-multiply by $L$, and take the trace. By linearity of the latter, the equation is equivalent to
$$
\mbox{tr} (L^TPXZL)+\mbox{tr} (L^TZXPL)=0.
$$
Actually, we will see that both matrices above are zero.

**Step 2:** since $A$ is symmetric, $\ker A=\ker A^T=(\mbox{im } A)^\perp$. This explains why the projections (=self-adjoint idempotents) $P$ and $Z$ are complementary, i.e. $P+Z=I$. Note that in particular 
$$
PZ=P(I-P)=P-P^2=(I-P)P=ZP \quad\Rightarrow\quad PZ=ZP=0.
$$

**Step 3:** since $A-bI$ commutes with $A$, so does $X$. Hence $\ker A=\mbox{im } Z$ is invariant under $X$. Thus $ZXZ=XZ$, whence $ZX=(XZ)^T=Z^TX^TZ^T=ZXZ=XZ$. So $X$ commutes with $Z$, and with $P=I-Z$ as well. Therefore
$$
L^TPXZL=L^T(PZ)XL=0=L^T(ZP)XL=L^TZXPL
$$
which finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! By the way, can you explain in more detail on how you got '$\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{X}$'? I think it is used to prove $\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{X}\mathbf{Z}$, but I'm not 100% sure what you meant by *invariance*.

Comment: @FedericoMagallanez That's equivalent to $(1-Z)XZ=0$, ie the range of $XZ$ ($=X(\mbox{im }Z)$) is contained in the nullspace of $I-Z$ which is the range of $Z$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!